# Reporting on number of unique users that converted across any of their sessions

Tags: google-analytics, conversions

I'd like to create a custom report that looks something like this:

```
Country   |  Unique users  |  Likelihood of conversion  |  Average conversions

London    |  1000          |  9%                        |  5
Auckland  |  90            |  23%                       |  3
```

We'd like to eventually use this report to identify cities/countries that we should target in ad campaigns.

"Likelihood of conversion" is the likelihood that a specific user will complete a specific goal at least once across any of their sessions.

Initially I was thinking that "likelihood of conversion" was the same as a goal's "conversion rate", but it looks like conversion rate is calculated by doing something like {{Conversions}}/{{Users}}. As users can convert multiple times, this doesn't accurately represent what I'm wanting trying to show because the conversion rate is skewed based on single high-value users.

Answer (score 1):

If a user can convert multiple times, then the only way to get the 'Likelihood' metric is to use a separate query to get Users with a segment of sessions with conversions; then compare it to the Users without the segment.

Comment: So it's not possible to create the report above?

Comment: Not using the custom reporting capabilities in GA.